# How to create a hex dump of file containing only the hex characters without spaces in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, hex

How do I create an **unmodified** hex dump of a binary file in Linux using bash? The `od` and `hexdump` commands both insert spaces in the dump and this is not ideal.

Is there a way to simply write a long string with all the hex characters, minus spaces or newlines in the output?

Comment: See also: [How to print only the hex values from hexdump without line numbers or ASCII table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553493/how-to-print-only-the-hex-values-from-hexdump-without-line-numbers-or-ascii-tabl)

Answer (score 302):

```
xxd -p file
```

Or if you want it all on a single line:

```
xxd -p file | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: fyi To reverse the process: xxd -r -ps hexascii.txt file (it is ok with or without newlines)

Answer (score 119):

Format strings can make hexdump behave exactly as you want it to (no whitespace at all, byte by byte):

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"'
```

`1/1` means "each format is applied once and takes one byte", and `"%.2x"` is the actual format string, like in printf. In this case: 2-character hexadecimal number, leading zeros if shorter.

Comment: You need a `-v` or it will drop repeated bytes and replace them with an asterisk.

Comment: I wonder if hexdump itself is able to append the newline (only) to the end of output.. (obvious appendage of `; echo` makes it impossible to use as bash alias)

Comment: My alias: `alias to_hex="hexdump -ve '1/1 \"%.2x\"' && echo"`

Comment: The iteration count and byte count default to one, so 1/1 may be omitted, leaving the `hexdump -ve '"%.2x"'`

Comment: @mykhal, it's possible, if you know the number of bytes in output. Say if you use hexdump to output only 13 first bytes: `hexdump -n 13 -e '13/1 "%.2x" "\n"'`

Comment: You can reverse this output back into a  binary with `xdd -p -r < dump > file`

Answer (score 28):

It seems to depend on the details of the version of `od`. On OSX, use this:

```
od -t x1 -An file |tr -d '\n '
```

(That's print as type hex bytes, with no address. And whitespace deleted afterwards, of course.)

Comment: I would also add `-v` in this context, otherwise it skips repeats with `*`.

Answer (score 12):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'local $/; print unpack "H*", <>' file
```

Comment: Verified. Matches "xxd -p file | tr -d '\n'".

Comment: fyi To reverse the process: perl -e 'local $/; print pack "H*", <>' <hexascii.txt >file

Comment: The "local $/" is unnecessary.

Comment: Update to last comment: The "local $/" is unnecessary for "pack". For unpack, you need it but can alternatively put "undef $/". $/ is the line separator (default NL). undefined puts it into slurp-mode. So <> referenced in a string context pulls the whole binary file without parsing it into lines.

Comment: Alternate form: perl -e 'print unpack "H*", join("", <>)' <file

Comment: Alternate form 1 for reversal (hexascii to binary): perl -pe '$_=pack "H*", $_' <hexascii.txt >file

Comment: Alternate form 2 for reversal (hexascii to binary), removes any newlines (xxd -ps -r adds them): perl -pe 's/\n//g; $_=pack "H*", $_' <hexascii.txt >file

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python for this purpose:

```
python -c "print(open('file.bin','rb').read().hex())"
```

...where `file.bin` is your filename.

Explaination:

1. Open `file.bin` in `rb` (read binary) mode.
2. Read contents (returned as `bytes` object).
3. Use `bytes` method `.hex()`, which returns hex dump without spaces or new lines.
4. Print output.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are preferable, but for a pure Bash solution, I've modified the script in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003803/show-hexadecimal-numbers-of-a-file/2004276#2004276) to be able to output a continuous stream of hex characters representing the contents of a file. (Its normal mode is to emulate `hexdump -C`.)

Answer (score 2):

## tldr;

```
$ od -t x1 -A n -v <empty.zip | tr -dc '[:xdigit:]' && echo 
504b0506000000000000000000000000000000000000
$
```

## Explanation:

Use the `od` tool to print single hexadecimal bytes (`-t x1`) --- without address offsets (`-A n`) and without eliding repeated "groups" `(-v)` --- from `empty.zip`, which has been redirected to standard input. Pipe that to `tr` which deletes (`-d`) the complement (`-c`) of the hexadecimal character set (`'[:xdigit:]'`). You can optionally print a trailing newline (`echo`) as I've done here to separate the output from the next shell prompt.

## References:

- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html
- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html

Answer (score 2):

This code produces a "pure" hex dump string and it **runs faster than the all the
other examples given**.
It has been tested on 1GB files filled with binary zeros, and all linefeeds.
It is not data content dependent and reads 1MB records instead of lines.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\1e6} $_=unpack "H*"'
```

Dozens of timing tests show that for 1GB files, these other methods below are slower.
All tests were run writing output to a file which was then verified by checksum.
Three 1GB input files were tested: all bytes, all binary zeros, and all LFs.

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"'                    #  ~10x  slower
od -v -t x1 -An | tr -d "\n "               #  ~15x  slower
xxd -p | tr -d \\n                          #   ~3x  slower
perl -e 'local \$/; print unpack "H*", <>'  # ~1.5x  slower
- this also slurps the whole file into memory
```

To reverse the process:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\1e6} $_=pack "H*",$_'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most widely supported version (requiring only POSIX defined `tr` and `od` behavior):

```
cat "$file" | od -v -t x1 -A n | tr -d ' \n'
```

This uses `od` to print each byte as hex without address without skipping repeated bytes and `tr` to delete all spaces and linefeeds in the output. Note that not even the trailing linefeed is emitted here. (The `cat` is intentional to allow multicore processing where `cat` can wait for filesystem while `od` is still processing previously read part. Single core users may want replace that with `< "$file" od ...` to save starting one additional process.)

Comment: No need to use `cat` here, just pass the filename to `od`.

Comment: I agree that historically connecting stdin is considered better and it's still the correct solution for single core CPUs. However, with modern systems with many idle cores in a single socket CPU, I think it's better to allow `cat` to read pipe buffer worth of input in parallel with the `od` at all times.  This reduces the possibility of `od` stalling for reading the file.

Comment: I did some microbenchmarks and it seems that using the `cat` at the start does allow using multiple CPU cores for the task in parallel but in practice, the intercommunication between the cores causes so much extra work that avoiding the use of `cat` at the start of pipeline is still faster – at least for locally accessible files. In case the file was on remote network drive with slow connection, using the `cat` here could improve performance. That said, the `od` can only handle about 4 MB/s so it will be the bottleneck in most cases.