# Ascii/Hex convert in bash

Tags: bash, ascii, hex

I'm now doing it this way:

```
[root@~]# echo Aa|hexdump -v
0000000 6141 000a                              
0000003
[root@~]# echo -e "\x41\x41\x41\x41"
AAAA
```

But it's not exactly behaving as I wanted,

the hex form of `Aa` should be `4161`,but the output is `6141 000a`,which seems not making sense.

and when performing hex to ascii,is there another utility so that I don't need the prefix `\x` ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614764/how-to-create-a-hex-dump-of-file-containing-only-the-hex-characters-without-spac/2614831#2614831

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The reason is because `hexdump` by default prints out 16-bit integers, not bytes. If your system has them, `hd` (or `hexdump -C`) or `xxd` will provide less surprising outputs - if not, `od -t x1` is a POSIX-standard way to get byte-by-byte hex output. You can use `od -t x1c` to show both the byte hex values and the corresponding letters.

If you have `xxd` (which ships with vim), you can use `xxd -r` to convert back from hex (from the same format `xxd` produces). If you just have plain hex (just the '4161', which is produced by `xxd -p`) you can use `xxd -r -p` to convert back.

Comment: `xxd -p -r AAA`,this doesn't work,can it retrieve parameters from command line directly?

Comment: no... and the 'r' converts back from hex, you'd want something like '`echo 4161 | xxd -r -p`' or '`echo Aa | xxd -p`'

Comment: Just FYI `xxd` is broken as of now. It desplays all zeroes instead of data. Maybe specific to my setup (xxd 2021-10-22, Ubuntu 22.04, large files > 2Gb), but anyway you should be aware of that (I lost some time to figure out what's going on).

Answer (score 32):

For the first part, try

```
echo Aa | od -t x1
```

It prints byte-by-byte

```
$ echo Aa | od -t x1
0000000 41 61 0a
0000003
```

The `0a` is the implicit newline that echo produces.

Use `echo -n` or `printf` instead.

```
$ printf Aa | od -t x1
0000000 41 61
0000002
```

Comment: How to convert hex back to ascii?

Comment: example: echo -e "\x68"

Answer (score 24):

```
$> printf "%x%x\n" "'A" "'a"
4161
```

Comment: @gdb: See [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) where it says: "If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote."

Comment: The c-style `printf` solution here should be the accepted answer. It is the most portable and the most simple, and keeps with POSIX compliance without needing external tools that may or may not be available.

Answer (score 23):

For single line solution:

```
echo "Hello World" | xxd -ps -c 200 | tr -d '\n'
```

It will print:

```
48656c6c6f20576f726c640a
```

or for files:

```
cat /path/to/file | xxd -ps -c 200 | tr -d '\n'
```

For reverse operation:

```
echo '48656c6c6f20576f726c640a' | xxd -ps -r
```

It will print:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash :

```
a=abcdefghij    
for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++));do printf %02X \'${a:$i:1};done
```

6162636465666768696A

Comment: wrong output for some characters like (space, tab, \r,\n) all of these characters will be shown as \x00

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
> echo Aa | tr -d '\n' | xxd -p
4161

> echo 414161 | tr -d '\n' | xxd -r -p
AAa
```

The `tr -d '\n'` will trim any possible newlines in your input

Comment: On macOS you can also use `echo -n Aa` instead of `echo Aa | tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: @p13rr0m You are right, It should also work on all *nix systems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how it crazy it looks but it does the job really well

```
ascii2hex(){ a="$@";s=0000000;printf "$a" | hexdump | grep "^$s"| sed s/' '//g| sed s/^$s//;}
```

Created this when I was trying to see my name in HEX ;)
use how can you use it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Text2Conv="Aa"
for letter in $(echo "$Text2Conv" | sed "s/\(.\)/'\1 /g");do printf '%x' "$letter";done
```

*4161*

The trick is using sed to parse the Text2Conv to format we can then seperate anf loop using for.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the correct thing

```
echo "Hello, world!" | tr -d '\n' | xxd -ps -c 200
```

Comment: `echo -n "Hello, world!" | xxd -ps -c 200` would also work

Comment: I typically use `xxd -ps -c 200 <<< "Hello, world!"`

Answer (score 1):

here a little script I wrote to convert ascii to hex. hope it helps:

```
echo '0x'"`echo 'ASCII INPUT GOES HERE' | hexdump -vC |  awk 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {$1=""; print }' | awk '{sub(/\|.*/,"")}1'  | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' '`" | rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

SteinAir's answer above was helpful to me -- thank you! And below is a way it inspired, to convert hex strings to ascii:

```
for h in $(echo "4161" | sed "s/\(..\)/\1 /g"); do printf `echo "\x$h"`;done
Aa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n Aa | hexdump -e '/1 "%02x"'; echo
```

Answer (score 0):

according to http://mylinuxbook.com/hexdump/ you might use the hexdump format parameter

```
echo Aa | hexdump -C -e '/1 "%02X"'
```

will return `4161`

to add an extra linefeed at the end, append another formatter.

BUT: the format given above will give multiplier outputs for repetitive characters

```
$ printf "Hello" | hexdump -e '/1 "%02X"' 
48656C*
6F
```

instead of

```
48656c6c6f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ echo -n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog | python -c "print raw_input().encode('hex'),"
54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f67
jcomeau@aspire:~$ echo -n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog | python -c "print raw_input().encode('hex')," | python -c "print raw_input().decode('hex'),"
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

it could be done with Python3 as well, but differently, and I'm a lazy dog.

Comment: `python` != `bash`

Comment: neither are `sed`, `hexdump`, `printf`, `awk`, or `xxd`.

Comment: it's shorter than some of the other solutions and arguably more readable. and it converts both ways, from the Bash command line. I don't see your point.

Comment: The point is, he asked for a bash solution. Meaning, as per his context, bashisms or bash built-ins. You didn't provide this with python solution(s).

Answer (score -1):

echo append a carriage return at the end.

Use

```
echo -e
```

to remove the extra 0x0A

Also, hexdump does not work byte-per-byte as default. This is why it shows you bytes in a weird endianess and why it shows you an extra 0x00.