# Bash: how to get a byte from a number?

Tags: linux, bash, casting, busybox

I want to convert a number to its byte equivalent. Currently I do this:

```
echo $((0xe0)) | hexdump -c
```

And I get this output:

```
0000000   2   2   4  \n
```

What I want to get is:

```
0000000 e0
```

How should I do?

Comment: checkout (could be helpful) http://stackoverflow.com/q/5724761/1007273

Comment: But `echo $((0xe0))` will output `224`, which is a String, consisting of 3 characters: 2,2 and 4. It's not the number 224, nor a character with the hexadecimal value 224.

Comment: @Konerak: That's the point of the question.

Comment: Too bad there is no answer that actually accepts the input from STDIN (or using a pipe) then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
printf '\xe0'

echo -ne '\xe0'
```