# bash ascii to hex

Tags: bash, hex, ascii

was wondering if anyone could help me with converting ascii to hex in bash.
Example code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
STR = "hello"
#Convert to hex
HEXVAL = $STR #(in hex here?)
```

I want hexval to have the value:
68656C6C6F (hello in hex)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [Have you already tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) People are more eager to help if you show some research effort before asking. Otherwise, you will appear as a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724761/ascii-hex-convert-in-bash

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$ str="hello"
$ hex="$(printf '%s' "$str" | xxd -p -u)"
$ echo "$hex"
68656C6C6F
```

Or:

```
$ hex="$(printf '%s' "$str" | hexdump -ve '/1 "%02X"')"
$ echo "$hex"
68656C6C6F
```

Careful with the `'"%X"'`; it has both single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: On `xxd V1.10 27oct98`, I have to use `xxd -p -u`.

Comment: "xxd -pu" worked for me, but I thought I'd mention that the other suggestion had an entirely different output.

Comment: hexdump reads by 4 bites so the "6C6C6568A6F" is incorrect. It is "lleho"

Comment: @Hedgehog Wow, and yikes! I've fixed both examples.

Answer (score 12):

You have several options

```
$ printf hello | xxd
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f                             hello
```

See also:
[Ascii/Hex convert in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724761/ascii-hex-convert-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Pure BASH convertor of string to printable hexadecimal sequence and back

```
str2hex_echo() {
    # USAGE: hex_repr=$(str2hex_echo "ABC")
    #        returns "0x410x420x43"
    local str=${1:-""}
    local fmt="0x%x"
    local chr
    local -i i
    for i in `seq 0 $((${#str}-1))`; do
        chr=${str:i:1}
        printf  "${fmt}" "'${chr}"
    done
}

hex2str_echo() {
    # USAGE: ASCII_repr=$(hex2str_echo "0x410x420x43")
    #        returns "ABC"
    echo -en "'${1:-""//0x/\\x}'"
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

ASCII->hex: The secret sauce of efficient conversion from character to its underlying ASCII code is feature in `printf` that, with non-string format specifiers, takes leading character being a single or double quotation mark as an order to produce the underlying ASCII code of the next symbol. This behavior is documented in [GNU BASH reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf), but is also exposed in details together with many other other wonderful utilities in Greg's (also known as [GreyCat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat)'s) wiki page [BashFAQ/071](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) dedicated to char-ASCII conversions.

Comment: Using "seq" is not pure-bash!

But I have a simplified "seq" function written in pure-bash :-)

Comment: Why use `seq`? Why not just `for ((i = 0; i < ${#str}; ++i))`?

Comment: Why use `fmt` instead of putting the format string inline? e.g., `printf '0x%x' "'${chr}"`

Comment: This will now fail due to unicode character handling...
 which come out as utf16 hex codes.

Answer (score 1):

here's a one liner (a little complex but works fine):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '0x'"`echo $1 | hexdump -vC |  awk 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {$1=""; print }' | awk '{sub(/\|.*/,"")}1'  | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' '`" | rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xxd -p -u <<< "$STR" | sed 's/\(..\)/0x&, /g; s/, $//;'
```

> 0x68, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x0A

Answer (score 0):

Only hex line output. Tested, both systems verified.

```bash
# Linux
$ echo -n 'hello' | hexdump -ve '/1 "%02x"'
68656c6c6f
```

```bash
# Mac
$ echo -n 'hello' | xxd -p -c 256
68656c6c6f
```

Comment: `0a` should not be at the end of the string.

Comment: @deweydb how to rewrite my solution?)

Comment: try `echo -n 'hello' | hexdump -ve '/1 "%02x"'` 
and 
`echo -n 'hello' | xxd -p -c 256` https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo

Answer (score 0):

**POSIX option**

I think this one [is POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755):

```
od-raw() {
  od -A n -t x1 -v | tr -d ' \n' 
}
```

Usage:

```
printf hello | od-raw
```

Output:

```
68656c6c6f
```

Or if you want separating spaces:

```
os-raw-spaces() {
  od -A n -t x1 -v "$@" | tr -d '\n' | cut -c 2-
}
```

Output:

```
68 65 6c 6c 6f
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.

Related:

- [How to create a hex dump of file containing only the hex characters without spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614764/how-to-create-a-hex-dump-of-file-containing-only-the-hex-characters-without-spac/2614831#2614831)