# Transform hexadecimal information to binary using a Linux command

Tags: c, command, command-line-arguments, binaryfiles, hexdump

I have this binary file on my Linux system...

```
 udit@udit-Dabba ~ $ cat file.enc
 Salted__s�bO��<0�F���Jw!���]�:`C�LKȆ�l
```

Using the hexdump command, I see its information like this:

```
 udit@udit-Dabba ~ $ hexdump -C file.enc
 00000000  53 61 6c 74 65 64 5f 5f  1b 73 a1 62 4f 15 be f6  |Salted__.s.bO...|
 00000010  3c 30 cc 46 ee 10 13 11  84 bf 4a 77 21 a4 84 99  |<0.F......Jw!...|
 00000020  0e 5d ef 11 18 3a 60 43  a0 4c 4b 1e c8 86 e6 6c  |.]...:`C.LK....l|
 00000030
```

Now I am given a file on some other system whose contents are like this:

```
 53 61 6c 74 65 64 5f 5f  1b 73 a1 62 4f 15 be f6
 3c 30 cc 46 ee 10 13 11  84 bf 4a 77 21 a4 84 99
 0e 5d ef 11 18 3a 60 43  a0 4c 4b 1e c8 86 e6 6c
```

And I need to find out that same exact binary information from this hexdump.

How can I proceed for that?

If there isn't any switch for that then C code will also work fine.

(But a Linux command with some switch is preferable)

**Limitation:**

The binary information in the file is output of an encryption algorithm, so contents should exactly match...

Comment: Have a look at [xxd](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xxd/)

Comment: @user786653 Thnx It helped I knew about `-r` and not `-p` and needed it soon ... so posted the question

Comment: About the same subject, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614764/hex-dump-of-file-in-bash

Answer (score 237, accepted):

As @user786653 suggested, use the [`xxd(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xxd/) program:

```
xxd -r -p input.txt output.bin
```

Comment: to add use 
`echo "hex" | xxd -r -p - `
to take input from piped standard out

Comment: Can also be used to get binary hashes - like `echo something | sha256sum | xxd -r -p -`

Comment: To explain the flags: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=xxd+-r+-p

Comment: Note that `xxd` uses very old fashioned argument processing, so all of the following behave differently: `xxd -rp` `xxd -pr` `xxd -r -p`. Only the last of the three works for this use case.

Comment: @Amanpreet no need to do that because the man page says that `If no infile is given, standard input is read.`