# Convert hex-dump to binary file

Tags: python, perl, awk, hexdump

I have some hex dumps that look like this:

```
0x000eb3a8 0005a5a8 0005a5b0    ........
0x000eb3b0 000e8918 0005a7b8    ........
0x000eb3b8 00056018 00000001    ..`.....
0x000eb3c0 00000000 000b8450    .......P
0x000eb3c8 000b83b0 00000007    ........
0x000eb3d0 000b8378 000b8358    ...x...X
0x000eb3d8 000cef70 000c95f8    ...p....
```

I want to parse the two columns in the middle, read them byte by byte (obviously, two characters represent one byte in hex notation) and write each byte into a *binary* file. I tried with `awk`, but couldn't find a way to write binary output. Can somebody help me? Any other tool or scripting language (perl, python, sed, zsh, ...) would also be accepted.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `xxd`?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826526/transform-a-hex-info-to-binary-using-linux-command
http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd

Comment: perl has `pack` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html which is useful for just that kind of conversion

Comment: Amazing! I knew `xxd` before, but didn't know it can also reverse hex dumps. Thanks a lot!