# C executable to hex

Tags: cmake, hex, avr, clion, avrdude

I am using CLion as IDE. After building the output is an executable file `example`. What I would like to achieve is make `.hex` file from it and upload it to my AVR via `avrdude`. I read and tried some [possible solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614764/how-to-create-a-hex-dump-of-file-containing-only-the-hex-characters-without-spac)

```
xxd -p example | tr -d '\n' > example.hex
```

and

```
avrdude -u -c usbasp-clone -p atmega8 -P /dev/bus/usb/001/006 -U flash:w:example.hex
```

but `avrdude` outputs

```
avrdude: input file example.hex auto detected as invalid format
avrdude: invalid input file format: -1
avrdude: read from file 'example.hex' failed
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool for extracting sections from an executable and converting them into another format is `objcopy`.

```
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex example example.hex
```

Or if your avrdude is built with ELF support then you can use the executable directly.

```
avrdude -c usbasp-clone -p atmega8 -U flash:w:example
```

Comment: Brilliant! The last example was the one.