# Send data as bytes to pipe in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I recently spent some time trying to write some numbers as bytes to pipe using bash (e.g. 10 as `0xA`, not `0x310x30`). Unfortunately I was not able to do so and had to rewrite the script into Python. Is it any way to send data as bytes in bash script and not as characters?

Comment: You might be interested in my pure-Bash implementation of `hexdump` found in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2004276/26428) and distributed as an example script with Bash 4.2.

Comment: related: [How to convert an unsigned decimal (less than 1<<32) to 4 bytes (binary) in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157648/1321)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chepner told, you can output any value as e.g.: $'\012'. So, a short script:

```
convert() {
    printf \\$(printf '%03o' $1)
}
convert 122 | od -bc
```

The right print will convert the decimal argument into octal number and the second print will print the octal number as above... e.g. decimal 65 will be converted into byte 'A'.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify arbitrary characters in `bash` using `$'...'` syntax. `$'\012'` `$'\x0a'` would be the byte with decimal value 10 in octal and hex, respectively. See the `bash` man page under QUOTING.

Comment: What if I want to send something that I have e.g. in `testVar` variable? I tried to use `$'...'` syntax but without success.

Comment: Then it's up to the reader of the variable to treat the value as a sequence of bytes, rather than a sequence of printable characters. You don't have to do anything special.