# Cannot brew install node - Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully

Tags: node.js, terminal, homebrew

### Question (Summarized for 2024)

I am trying to upgrade my node via homebrew but ran into a problem, i had the following error

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
```

I also tried to brew link node but that doesn't work either.

---

### Editor Note (2024):

This original question had notes and error logs from issues over a decade ago. The people arriving at this question now just are looking for a solution to  "Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully", and there are plenty, so deleting the obsolete details.

Answer (score 266):

There are two steps involved.

1. Simply run these four commands:

```
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/include/node
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib/dtrace
```

2. Finally, run the overwrite command:

```
    brew link --overwrite node
```

Comment: I had to run `sudo chown -R \`whoami\`:admin /usr/local/lib/dtrace ` as well. Thanks.

Comment: I needed to add `sudo chown -R \`whoami\`:admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`

Comment: I needed to add ```sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules```

Comment: Confirming that the Feb 13, 2020 edit still works on mac as of Jan 7, 2024, i updated to Node v21.6.1

Answer (score 33):

I ran into this same issue under the same circumstances. I was able to get the brew version to install successfully by:

1. Run `brew install node`
2. Make note of the module that is causing the issue and delete it. In your case, this would be `/usr/local/include/node`
3. Uninstall - `brew uninstall node`
4. Re-install - `brew install node`

I had to repeat this process a few times for each remaining problematic directory (about 3 different ones in actuality), and the install eventually succeeded without any issues.

Comment: this worked for me. i actually had node installed manually without brew - so the problem was caused by trying to use brew to install node after node was already installed manually

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this problem on a new MacBook Pro on Mac OS High Sierra.  I gleaned brew was trying to use directories named include and lib under /usr/local that was not there.  Since root owns /usr I had to do it manually - making sure that `whoami` owner matches peer directories in /usr/local:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/include
chown `whoami`:admin /usr/local/include 
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib
chown `whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib
```

And then to match the other directories in /usr/local I did:

```
chmod 775 /usr/local/include
chmod 775 /usr/local/lib
```

then the following worked:

```
brew uninstall node 
brew install node
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to make `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/share` writable. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable) answer to achieve this. Below is the key advice in the answer replicated in case the link breaks:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
```

Comment: dumb question but do you actually run 'whoami' or is that a placeholder for your username on your machine?

Comment: If you type `whoami` into your command prompt, you'll see that it evaluates to the logged-in user.

Comment: @EthanParker Backticks will cause the command to be substituted, similar to `$(whoami)`. For more info about the difference between the two, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929799/2533467

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.0...
Error: Could not symlink include/node /usr/local/include is not writable.
```

Solution:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/include
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
$ brew link node
```

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.0... 7 symlinks created

`$ node -v` => v11.10.0

`$ npm -v` => 6.7.0

Answer (score 12):

`brew postinstall node` or `brew link --overwrite node` doesn't seem to help.

After several rounds of `brew uninstall node` and `brew install node` the following were the offending directories and files:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/node
sudo rm -r /usr/local/share/doc/node
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
```

After the offending files are removed `brew` will do all the proper linking with permissions for you.

Likely permissions were set as `root:wheel` because of a past install with `sudo` or perhaps manual installation, etc.

Comment: The answer that did help in 2019 (2019-10-16)

Comment: This worked for me in 2021. Before installing brew I've installed the node manually which cause the error. After trying so many things, this ^^ finally worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to remove the folder `/usr/local/share/systemtap` as well

Answer (score 9):

For those running high sierra on MacOS:

I tried giving permissions using the `chown` command and uninstalling then reinstalling node via homebrew but nothing worked.

I just went to this site https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and downloaded the 64 bit macOS .pkg and it worked perfectly. I tested it by just entering the command `node` in terminal.

[image: image of which version of node to download for mac]

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar problem with linking.  I couldn't get it to work. I tried to chmod /usr/local/include/node so I could write the link to it but ran into another error.  As a final solution, I just reinstalled node from https://nodejs.org/download/

I have a working node prompt again!  I would love to go through brew to update but it saved me a lot of hassle just using the pkg installer from the site.  I know this may not be the solution you are looking for but I just wanted to share my experience with the same issue.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Would reinstalling the node version from the official website create conflicts with the old one? Did you remove the old one and reinstall or just download the pkg file and click the install button?

Comment: No, I just downloaded the pkg from the website and everything worked well.

Answer (score 2):

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

Error: Could not symlink (...)

/usr/xxx

```
sudo chown -R 'whoami?':admin xxx
brew link --overwrite node
```

Rinse and repeat

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to run brew doctor which showed me that I did not have write access and had to run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/man` to fix the issue.

I suggest running `brew doctor` to see if it can provide some hints on the issue

Answer (score 1):

remove the error folder or file manually and run this command `brew uninstall node && brew install node`

You have to do this process till all error folder and files are removed.

Then node will be linked.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to `brew link node` and it says something along the lines:

> Error: Could not symlink include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
>   Target /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
>   already exists. You may want to remove it:

Try this:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run node | xargs rm
brew link node
```