# "concurrently command not found" but installed gloabally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm using macOs and even though concurrently is installed globally through npm, when setting it as a start script in package.json and typing `npm start` the following error occurs.

```
concurrently - kill-others "npm run server" "npm run client"
sh: concurrently - kill-others: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! thesis_fullstack@1.0.0 start: `concurrently - kill-others "npm run server" "npm run client"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the thesis_fullstack@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mantzaris/.npm/_logs/2020-04-25T22_40_12_897Z-debug.log
```

My package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "thesis_fullstack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "cd server && npm start",
    "start": "concurrently - kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously don't know what I did to fix it. First of all i fixed the command flag "typo" to concurrently --kill-others your_commands_here. Then i uninstalled node manually and reinstalled it through Homebrew (since I'm using MacOs). After that node and npm wouldn't work at all. Fixed it with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583099/13212764. I think by that point running npm start worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the dependency locally in order to use it in any of your start scripts. run

```
npm install --save concurrently
```

to install it locally in your project

Comment: the command is probably wrong. according to the documentation use concurrently --kill-others your_commands_here

Comment: Not working even after this change... Command concurrently --kill-others not found

Answer (score 2):

For

Globally -
`npm install -g concurrently`

Locally -
`npm install concurrently`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not with the package itself, you can either have it globally or save it locally (not --save-dev).

You can find the solution for your problem looking at the error log

```
concurrently - kill-others "npm run server" "npm run client"
sh: concurrently - kill-others: command not found
```

The command should be either --kill-others or -k for short, here is the official documentation: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently

Try this as your package.json

```
{
  "name": "thesis_fullstack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "cd server && npm start",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.5.1"
  }
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Not working either... Is something wrong with my path? I have concurrently installed both locally and globally

Comment: What is the error code after changing it to --kill-others?

Comment: same error with new dash added: concurrently --kill-others: command not found. Anyways managed to fix it. Explanation is in my answer. Thanks