# Unbrewed header files found in /usr/local/include

Tags: homebrew, brew-doctor

I got the following after running 'brew doctor' and have no idea how to delete them. How do I delete them? I tried to install python 3 after and then got an error saying that some kegs didn't link so I followed the command to overwrite it and now Im back to python 2. but anyways, how do I fix this error with homebrew? Everytime I run brew doctor it says this:

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:

```
 /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the brew page for more information

- Unbrewed files mean that these files were not added by Homebrew itself
- The issue seems to be with the Node.js package. If you don't use Node.js you can delete them without an issue. If you do use it try uninstalling (or manually deleting `/usr/local/include/node`) and reinstalling.

**Please Note:**

- In general Unbrewed headers are just used by Homebrew to find debug information
- So if your issue is fixed you can safely ignore this issue.

Also refer to this answer: [can't brew install node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691626/cant-brew-install-node)