# Node not installing properly

Tags: node.js

So, brew isn't really working for me, it keeps giving me these errors. When I tried to re-install it, it gave me this:

```
virtu0us:~ lik20$ brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: node 14.5.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
```

So when I tried to do that,

```
virtu0us:~ lik20$ brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: node 14.5.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
virtu0us:~ lik20$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.5.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
Target /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

So I did this:

```
virtu0us:~ lik20$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.5.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
Target /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
virtu0us:~ lik20$ brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.5.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `brew uninstall node`?

Comment: Yes, that's why this error happened

Comment: Have you tried `rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'`?

Comment: There is a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691626/cant-brew-install-node).  Did you checked that?