# Cannot update version of node - unexpected token

Tags: macos, npm, node-modules

Downgraded my node recently for a tech assessment to vers 12, now wanted to upgrade but seems something is wrong. Ive tried a heap of things that everyone suggests.

Not a very proficient mac user, so any help appreciated

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g n
ERROR: npm v9.1.2 is known not to run on Node.js v12.22.12. You'll need to
upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This
version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 ||
>=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:22
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:76:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

```
-MacBook-Pro ~ % node -v
v12.22.12
```

Tried npm install -g n

Comment: Anyone updating Node in 2024 and using Brew can also read through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691626/cant-brew-install-node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the OSX installer on nodejs.org/. It will update your local node installation and also a compatible npm version (v8.19.2 as of writing). Then the error should be gone when typing `node -v`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issues because I was working on an older project with an older version of npm and node being used.

For me, I just had to reference an older version from node from the one I was currently using (`nvm install 10`) and I was able to use npm correctly again. From there, I did `npm cache clean --force` to clear my cache, and was able to reinstall the version of node i needed which was along the lines of (`npm install node@xx.xx.x -g`).

Answer (score 2):

```
ERROR:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:22
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

To resolve these issues, you have to delete node and npm from your system and reinstall both of them. then you can resolve this issues.

1. First of all install Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Type the following command to install Node.js and NPM:
3. brew install node
4. To check node version: node -v
5. To check npm version: npm -v

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issue. For older project, I need to use node 12 only but now I can't use npm anymore AFTER I have somehow upgraded my npm to higher version.

```
ERROR:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:22
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: To check list of installed node versions please run command below
```nvm ls```

Then use following command to use specified node version
```nvm use 12.14.1```

Then please run following command to check you are using correct version
```nvm -v```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the reason was a mixture between the different node/npm version I used and `brew`was not really updating the node version I'm using

There was another version in `/usr/local/bin` and this was not impacted by any  update by `brew update node`. So the recommendation is to check what version you are using:

> node -v

> whereis node

Then check with `brew doctor` if the node is really successful installed. I found this problem on my installation:

> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
> Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that > depend on those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` > on these:
>
> node

With the command `brew link node` you will guided through the files that you have to delete before "brew" could install the latest node version (really) successful. After the linking was successful the problem has disappear at my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a windows machine

I tried to uninstall node and then re-install it, but I kept getting the same error when trying to install an older version of npm. After some back and forth I realised that I had to COMPLETELY uninstall node and CLEAR cache directories at:

> c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Then installed node and problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu after downloading "Linux Binaries" from https://nodejs.org/en/download. I unpacked everything to a directory named *./foo*  and attempted to run `./foo/bin/npm`. The command failed because it picked an old version of node from my environment instead of using the new version in *./foo/bin/node*.

It works when adjusting $PATH like this:

```
PATH=./foo/bin:$PATH ./foo/bin/npm
```