# Why is lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_END) equal file size + 1?

Tags: c, linux, fseek

The system i am using is **Linux**.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

void main()
{
    int rbytes,wbytes,fd1,local;
    char buf[10],ch;
    fd1=open("f3.txt",O_RDONLY,0);
    local=lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_CUR);
    printf("The start file pointer position:%d\n",local);
    local=lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("End pointer position:%d\n",local);
    local=lseek(fd1,-10,SEEK_END);
    printf("-10 File pointer location:%d\n",local);
    rbytes=read(fd1,buf,5);
    buf[5]='\0';
    printf("buf=%s\n",buf);
    close(fd1);
}
```

Result:

[image]

The file's content of "f3.txt" is "123456789".

As we all know:

if the content is             123456789

the corresponding index is    012345678

**The value of lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_END) should be equal to '9', instead of '10'(base on the explanation of SEEK_END: the offset to the end of file), which confuse me a lot.
Why?**

The image of file content：

[The image of file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmReQ.png)

And the result of command 'wc':

[And the result of command 'wc'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1pu7.png)

Comment: Is the file's contents really "123456789" or does it include a newline at the end, e.g. "123456789\n"?

Comment: I'm going to rephrase Janne's question as the answer. It's because your text-file has a trailing line-feed (hex: 0x0A). Run "ls f3.txt -l" and confirm for yourself that the file size is 10.

Comment: @MatthewM. I'd make that "run `ls -l f3.txt`".

Comment: [How to view files in binary in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1765311/608639), [Show Hexadecimal Numbers Of a File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003803/608639), etc.

Comment: @SteveSummit Sure enough, I tried both variants... and the outputs of "ls" were identical.

Comment: copy text output and paste here, not in images

Comment: @MatthewM. Most Unix/Linux systems (though evidently not yours) require that options precede the filenames.  When I try `ls f3.txt -l` on my system, I get "`ls: -l: No such file or directory`", because it treats `-l` at the end as another filename, not an option flag.

Comment: Neither Ubuntu, Mint, nor RHEL7 take issue with it. That would cover quite a bit of Linux installations in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

If you created `f3.txt` using `vi` and putted `123456789` by default one new line char `\n`  added at end of line thats why `local=lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_END);` returns `10` that means plus one for `newline`.

you can run `wc f3.txt` on command line and can verify.

Comment: @egochen It shows that you did. That's why `wc` says 10 instead of 9.

Comment: To some extend, the problem has been dealt with. Thank you all!